# Selenium fails because of incompatible chromedriver and google-chrome versions although both are at the same version

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium with Google Chrome using Python 3 as follows:

```
chromedriver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, options=chrome_options)
```

The above code gives the error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:
>   session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
>   version 77

But both the `chromedriver` and `google-chrome` are version 77.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 77.0.3865.40 (f484704e052e0b556f8030b65b953dce96503217-refs/branch-heads/3865@{#442})

$ /usr/bin/google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 77.0.3865.75
```

Comment: Python version `3.?` Full error stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some quick code that user:797495 left me which can download chromedriver to path again at the right version, if it can't be found. Just add this to the beginning of your code:

```
curr_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
out = subprocess.getoutput(f"{chromedriver} -v")
if "ChromeDriver" in out:
    print(f"{out} \nChromeDriver exists in path and is executable" )
else:
    url = "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/72.0.3626.69/chromedriver_win32.zip"
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
        z.extractall()
        chromedriver =  f"{curr_dir}\chromedriver.exe"
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Cannot download chromedriver\n {e}")
```